# How can I specify the name of the element when a object will serialize

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following class

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName= "webSites")] //No capital w at the beginning
public class WebSites : List<WebSite>
{

}

public class WebSite
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { set; get; }
    [XmlAttribute("url")]
    public String Url { set; get; }
}
```

this is serialized to

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="DOS-862"?>
<webSites xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http:
//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <WebSite name="nice website" url="mydomain.com" />
```

this is almost ok but I want that `WebSite`(With a capital) will be `webSite` (no capital)
I know I can specify this only for the root, but how can I for an internal member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[XmlType("webSite")]
public class WebSite {...}
```

or to control a collection property on a wrapper class:

```
[XmlArrayItem("webSite")]
[XmlArray("sites")]
public WebSites Sites { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for all the attributes, but didn't realize it was so easy :-)